# How to include URL suffix in pagination links in CI?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I can make a page example.com/index.php/products/view/shoes as example.com/index.php/products/view/shoes.html by adding suffix ".html" to the CI config.php file. [Ref: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html]

But when I generate the links in Pagination the suffix is not added to the generated links to the other pages.

Is there any setting we can do through configuration or do we need to modify the library file.

Comment: what do you mean by "suffix"?can you please post some example or code here.

Comment: Updated with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a suffix for pagination links this way:

```
$config['suffix'] = YOUR_SUFFIX
```

Look at my example:

URL : http://www.test_store.com/products/index/order/low_price

```
// Parsing the URI
$uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);

$page     = !empty($uri['page'])   ? $uri['page']   : 1;
$order    = !empty($uri['order'])  ? $uri['order']  : false;

// Search paginated
$this->Product->limit  = $per_page;
$this->Product->offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$this->Product->order  = $order;

$products = $this->Product->get_all();

// Pagination config
$config['base_url']         = site_url('products/index/page');
$config['total_rows']       = $this->Product->count_all();
$config['uri_segment']      = 4;
$config['num_links']        = 5;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['per_page']         = $per_page; 

// Add a suffix to pagination links
$config['suffix'] = !empty($uri['order']) ? '/order/'. $uri['order'] : ''; 

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

$pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

PD: I'm argentinian and my english skills are a little poor

Comment: If I pass the base url with extension then it didn't work, otherwise works fine. But for the first page I don't get suffix when I don't pass it in the base_url. How can I do that?

Comment: You can append the extension this way: $config['suffix'] = '.html';

Comment: It works for the pages but not to the first page. First page only get base_url.

Answer (score 0):

In your application/config/config.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Comment: As I explained in the question, this is working for links generated using anchor() function but not for the links in Pagination.

Comment: Post your pagination code. For pagination you need to create them manually.

Comment: In pagination I am passing the base_url without the suffix otherwise it generates code like www.example.com/controller/method.html/page/1 which will not work. I want to generate code like www.example.com/controller/method/page/1.html but I couldn't find any param for suffix in pagination to pass extension only base_url